# Консоль быстро изчезает

Tags: windows, c++, консоль

Установил на нетбук Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express , купил самоучитель по с++,

распечатал с него вот эту программку

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main ( )
{
    // объявление и инициализация массива array
    int array [ ] = { 5, -10, 123, -7, 25, -3, -77, 1, 7, 3 } ;
    // вычисление size — количества элементов в массиве
    int size = sizeof ( array ) / sizeof ( array [ 0 ] ) ;
    // предположение, что минимальный элемент имеет индекс 0
    int jMin = 0 ;
    // цикл проверки элементов массива
    for ( int j = 1; j < size; j++ )
        if ( array [ j ] < array [ jMin ] ) 
            jMin = j ;
    // вывод массива
    cout << "Elements of array\n" ;
    for ( int j = 0; j < size; j++ )
        cout << array [ j ] << '\t' ;
    // вывод минимального значения array [ jMin ]
    cout << "\nMinimum = " << array [ jMin ] << endl ;
    exit (0) ;
}
```

компилирую ее, консоль  появляется и   быстро  исчезает, не подскажете, в чем проблема?

Comment: Программа выполняется до конца и завершает работу. Вы даже exit(0); прописали. Хотите, чтоб машина выполняла этот код 20 секунд?))

Comment: Если также как в шарпе, то можно ctrl+f5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как варианты:

- В конце программы припиши функцию getch(), которая ожидает нажатие клавиши. И добавь в include conio.h.
- Запустить в режиме отладки и поставить точку останова на последнюю строчку кода.

Comment: @Андрей2 поставте галочку рядом с понравившимся ответом чтобы вопрос не висел в неотвеченных

Answer (score 3):

Есть очень много вариантов. Приведу некоторые из них. Первый - запросить ввод данных с консоли:

```
int value;
cin >> value;
```

Второй - бесконечный цикл(не самый хороший вариант, потому что полностью нагружает ядро процессора):

```
for(;;);
```

Третий:

```
system("pause");
```

Только надо для этого подключить какой-то заголовочный файл, не помню какой.

Comment: Для работы system("pause") в коде уже есть всё необходимое, пространство std и iostream.

Comment: Проверил, работает.

Comment: Ну раз работает, что ответ не подтверждаешь!?